# Concerning the meaning of "of" in "less of"

Tags: prepositions

Which specific meaning does the preposition *of*  takes on within:

> It was less **of** a thought than I expected.

?

---

Edit: the original phrase (before the first answer) was:

> It was less **of** a thought than a feeling.

Answer (score 2):

To my ear, that is ungrammatical, a mistake for "it was less a thought than a feeling".

Probably a blend with the different structure "It was less of a thought than I expected".